# Search Filter in Java and MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing

I am writing a code in Java where user can type a last name in a JTextField named lastname and then search for possible match in MySQL database. Say for example, user begins to type letter "M" (case insensitive and without double quotes), all the last name that starts with letter "M****" will display on JTable. If user types a second letter, say for example "A", the results on JTable will only display last names with "MA***", then if user types third letter, say for example "N", JTable will only display all the last names with "MAN***" and so on..

I have read about

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE lastname LIKE value

and tried to use it on my program, however, I am getting an error.

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxError.Exception: You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%' at line 1

Here's my partial code in event when there's key pressed in JTextField lastname:

```
private void lastNameKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    

  Connection conn = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "students_dbs";
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String databaseUserName = "user1";
    String databasePassword = "test";
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    try{
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, databaseUserName, databasePassword);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    System.out.println("Connected to the database.");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Failed to connect ot the database.");
    }


try{
String sql = "SELECT studentno, lastname, firstname, middlename FROM student WHERE lastname LIKE '%" + lastname.getText() + "'%";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
result = pst.executeQuery();
studentsTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(result));
}
catch(Exception e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}  
}
```

I googled it for a day or two now, however, I am stuck. I'm kinda new in using LIKE in MySQL. Any kind help is very much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Print the final value of `sql` variable please.

Comment: Consider getting the entire data using SQL, then filtering the table using a [`RowSorter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html) - *"`RowSorter` provides the basis for sorting **and filtering.** .."*

Comment: LIKE '%" + lastname.getText() + "'%" --> LIKE '%" + lastname.getText() + "%' "

Comment: @Jakub Kania is it this? `String sql = "SELECT studentno, lastname, firstname, middlename FROM student WHERE lastname LIKE '%" + lastname.getText() + "'%";` ?

@AndrewThompson hmm. you mean like all the data in my SQL table will be displayed in my JTable, then filter search from JTable instead of filtering search directly in MySQL table? I haven't thought of that. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

@Alexander_Winter I have tried it and gave me no error, thank you. However, it displayed all the data in my SQL table instead of filtering.

Comment: I meant the value you'd get after printing that value, the one with string already glued together. But it seems @royu found the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position of the last ' char is wrong:

```
String sql = "SELECT studentno, lastname, firstname, middlename FROM student 
              WHERE lastname LIKE '% " + lastname.getText() + " '% ";
```

should be:

```
String sql = "SELECT studentno, lastname, firstname, middlename FROM student 
              WHERE lastname LIKE '% " + lastname.getText() + " %' ";
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried it and gave me no error. Thanks! However, it displayed all the data in my SQL database and didn't filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String SQL="Select name from tablename where like %";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, txnam.gettext()+"%");
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

put one textfield for u to type

```
String sql = "SELECT studentno, lastname, firstname, middlename FROM student 
              WHERE lastname=?";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1,jTextField1.getText());
result = pst.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score -2):

## you can use this code :

[this is sql code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sctnA.png)

and then rename youre Jtabble, Like model in picture one. then call method in here  initcomponent(){selectDataTable(""); }. then make event key released in youre textfield, and then write this in the event selectDatatable(textfield.gettext()); Done

Comment: Please format your code with the {} button. Your answer will benefit from an explanation, what your code does. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)